# MVC 3 ASP.NET and Connecting 2 Databases

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Currently working on a web application in ASP.NET, MVC3 that allows people to view items, and change anything. This is with using my own database that I have created, but this I have found is good for generally viewing anything on the application but not good for security purposes to prevent them seeing particular things, and I do not want to waste my time removing tables and re-adding them.

So... Is there a way to communicate between the ASPNETDB and my own Database which would allow users to login to the web application but also sign up as a customer?

Comment: You could always script the ASPNETDB schema and data, then copy it to your own database.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this using database roles, and only grant the appropriate roles to the user used to login to the two databases.

You have very granular control over what you want a db user to have access to.

Read up on databases and db roles